# Hibernate entity with @Any attribute throws a nullpointer exception when updating

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to use @Any annotation for a polymorphic relationship.

For demo purpose, I've created 3 classes:

- PcPlayer which implements Player interface
- ConsolePlayer which implements Player interface
- GameScore which contains a Player with @Any.

I can create a GameScore with a player without any trouble, but when I try to update it, a nullpointer exception occurs:

> Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.AttributeMapping.getAttributeMetadataAccess()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.Fetchable.asAttributeMapping()" is null.

Here's my code

**PcPlayer**

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
public class PcPlayer implements Player {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    private String username;

}
```

**ConsolePlayer**

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
public class ConsolePlayer implements Player {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    private String username;

}
```

**GameScore**

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Any;
import org.hibernate.annotations.AnyDiscriminator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.AnyDiscriminatorValue;
import org.hibernate.annotations.AnyKeyJavaClass;

@Entity
public class GameScore  {
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Any
    @AnyDiscriminator(DiscriminatorType.STRING)
    @AnyDiscriminatorValue(discriminator = "P", entity = PcPlayer.class)
    @AnyDiscriminatorValue(discriminator = "C", entity = ConsolePlayer.class)
    @AnyKeyJavaClass(Long.class)
    @Column(name ="player_type")
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_id")
    private Player player;  

}
```

**A service**

```
    PcPlayer pcPlayer = new PcPlayer();
    pcPlayer.setUsername("Mike");

    pcPlayerRepo.save(pcPlayer);

    GameScore game = new GameScore();
    game.setPlayer(pcPlayer);

    gameScoreRepository.save(game);

    // update some game's attributes

    gameScoreRepository.save(game); // Exception thrown...
```

Comment: This could be a bug. Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I didn't try to update my hibernate or Spring Boot versions, but it might have been fixed:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2935#event-9915627847